# I need to set the curent date to jdatechooser this code is not working

Tags: java, date, jdatechooser

I need to set the current date to jdatechooser this code is 
Not working

```
Date date = new Date ();
Jdatechooser.setDate(date);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a datechooser object.

```
Date date = new Date ();
JDateChooser dateChooser = new JDateChooser();
dateChooser.setDate(date);
```

Comment: I'm using jdatechooser and there is a red line under Date date =new Date(); that tells "no suitable constructor found for date"

Comment: Seems like you imported the wrong Date type. Check your imports for `import java.util.Date;`.